# assign NA value based on difference between observations

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I'm new to R and would like to ask for help in the code. I have a data frame "mydata" which includes multiple variables. But since some of my code failed to work, the data needs some cleaning. For example, in the minute-by-minute "Temp" column, some outliers popped up beyond the typical value around 28, such as 0,14,52...

Temp
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
39.8
14
28.5
28.5
38.8
0
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.5
28.6
28.6
52.1
28.6
28.6
28.5
28.4
28.3
28.3
28.2
28.2
28.2
28.2
28.2
0

I would like to write a if then statement to filter outliers out from all variables in this dataframe. The idea is something like:

```
for i in length(mydata) {
    if (mydata[,i]-mydata[,i-1]>10)
      mydata[,i] <- NA
}
```

To explain, for any variable mydata$x, if the absolute difference between observation x[i] and x[i-1] is greater than 10, then a NA value will be assigned to x[i].

The IF THEN statement seems difficult to me. Hope anyone could help by providing the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain your actual logic for filtering out the outliers? It *looks* like you might be interested in `diff`, but your question is not clear.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for the question, I may not say it clearly. Yes, I think I'm interested in diff statement. To be specific, for all variables in the dataframe, besides "temp" variable, I would like to write a IF statement that for all mydata$x[i] observation, if mydata$x[i]-mydata$x[i-1] > 10, then mydata$x[i] would be assigned a NA value.

Answer (score 0):

As you requested in the comments section, any value of `Temp` that changes by more than 10 degrees from the previous value (positive or negative) is replaced by NA with this:

```
mydata$Temp[c(FALSE, abs(diff(mydata$Temp)) > 10)] <- NA
```

However, this gets rid of more than just the outliers. It also excludes values that are simply returning from back to normal from an extreme value. For example, there's a point at which the temperature goes from 28.6 --> 52.1 --> 28.6. With this replacement, the values become 28.6 --> NA --> NA.

If you're just trying to get rid of the outliers, I'd recommend excluding values that fall outside a certain "normal" range, for example:

```
mydata$Temp[mydata$Temp < 18.6 | mydata$Temp > 38.6] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to treat multiple variables at one time besides the "temp" variable? I would like to assign NA values to all observations in the data frame when the difference between the observation and the previous observation is greater than 10.

Comment: Do you want to change it to NA if the absolute value is greater than 10, or only if the change is +10?

Comment: abs value is greater than 10

Comment: I'll respond to your comment about multiple variables when I see which of these you plan to use

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in the following way:

```
mydata$Temp <- lapply(mydata$Temp, function(x) if(x<38 & x > 18){x} else{NA}  )

> mydata <- data.frame( Temp = c(28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 38.8, 0, 28.5, 28.5, 50, 0.2, 0))
> mydata
   Temp
1  28.5
2  28.5
3  28.5
4  28.5
5  28.5
6  38.8
7   0.0
8  28.5
9  28.5
10 50.0
11  0.2
12  0.0
> mydata$Temp <- lapply(mydata$Temp, function(x) if(x<38 & x > 18){x} else{NA}  )
> mydata
   Temp
1  28.5
2  28.5
3  28.5
4  28.5
5  28.5
6    NA
7    NA
8  28.5
9  28.5
10   NA
11   NA
12   NA
```